# Execution order of RenderSection / RenderBody

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, underscore.js

In the `head` of my layout page I have a `@RenderSection("Head")` call that loads in script tags.

e.g:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//underscore-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
```

Then after the `head` I have another `@RenderSection` that renders my header (`@RenderSection("Header")`) -- this section contains [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/) syntax (`<%= myString %>`).

However when my page renders, it says `<%= myString %>` as plain text rather than replacing it with the variable text. However everything else that gets loaded on the page (that isn't part of the header, as in `@RenderBody()`) and contains Underscore syntax renders the way it's supposed to.

I've stepped through with the console, and it does appear that `RenderSection("Header")` happens before `RenderSection("Head")`. Shouldn't it be loading top-down?

How can I ensure that the `Head` is loaded before `Header` is loaded?

Comment: Razor renders out the sections in the order of calling `RenderSection` maybe your javascript in your `RenderSection("Header")` is executed before the `underscore` script loaded... try to to move your JavaScript logic into the DOM ready event...

Comment: Well I rely on the underscore script to remain inline.